# Spark Creating More then expected jobs | Databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am using Databricks to run below code, but i see 3 jobs created for the same.

I am trying to understand, why spark created 3 jobs which more or less do the same task

```
myschema = StructType([
 StructField("ID",StringType()),
 StructField("Eventype",StringType())
])
mydata = [Row('1','4/12/2023'),Row('2','4/13/2023'),Row('3','4/14/2023'),Row('4','4/15/2023')]
df = spark.createDataFrame(mydata,schema=myschema)
df.show()
```

Below are the dag visualisation of all 3 jobs

[image][image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Spark creating multiple jobs for one action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68522035/why-is-spark-creating-multiple-jobs-for-one-action)